# when IPv6 connectivity is broken, what's the best option : disabling ipv6 vs installing miredo?

Tags: 11.04, google-chrome, ipv6

I've finally found why my Google Chrome is so slow. And I've found these 2 posts.
The first on [Google Chrome forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6d4533621d76de91&hl=en) and the second one [here](http://www.davidhurst.co.uk/2008/05/06/debian-ubuntu-very-slow-to-resolve-dns-slow-dns-resolution-or-lookup/).
The solution suggested in the second post requires a modification of `/etc/modprobe.d/aliases`, but on my Ubuntu 11.04 I don't have such a file.

None of the resources i found would work on 11.04. Can anyone use anything that has worked and which is easily revertible?

Below are the result of `dig aaaa he.net` and `dig a he.net`

```
joseph@joseph-off-lap:~$ dig aaaa he.net

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> aaaa he.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15618
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 5, ADDITIONAL: 7

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;he.net.                IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
he.net.         58616   IN  AAAA    2001:470:0:76::2

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
he.net.         2031    IN  NS  ns2.he.net.
he.net.         2031    IN  NS  ns3.he.net.
he.net.         2031    IN  NS  ns4.he.net.
he.net.         2031    IN  NS  ns5.he.net.
he.net.         2031    IN  NS  ns1.he.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.he.net.     2044    IN  A   216.218.130.2
ns2.he.net.     2044    IN  A   216.218.131.2
ns2.he.net.     73027   IN  AAAA    2001:470:200::2
ns3.he.net.     2044    IN  A   216.218.132.2
ns3.he.net.     62719   IN  AAAA    2001:470:300::2
ns4.he.net.     2044    IN  A   216.66.1.2
ns4.he.net.     62719   IN  AAAA    2001:470:400::2

;; Query time: 134 msec
;; SERVER: 80.87.78.4#53(80.87.78.4)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul  4 17:02:33 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 290

joseph@joseph-off-lap:~$ dig a he.net

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> a he.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31069
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 5, ADDITIONAL: 7

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;he.net.                IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
he.net.         58533   IN  A   216.218.186.2

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
he.net.         1948    IN  NS  ns4.he.net.
he.net.         1948    IN  NS  ns5.he.net.
he.net.         1948    IN  NS  ns1.he.net.
he.net.         1948    IN  NS  ns2.he.net.
he.net.         1948    IN  NS  ns3.he.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.he.net.     1961    IN  A   216.218.130.2
ns2.he.net.     1961    IN  A   216.218.131.2
ns2.he.net.     72944   IN  AAAA    2001:470:200::2
ns3.he.net.     1961    IN  A   216.218.132.2
ns3.he.net.     62636   IN  AAAA    2001:470:300::2 
ns4.he.net.     1961    IN  A   216.66.1.2
ns4.he.net.     62636   IN  AAAA    2001:470:400::2

;; Query time: 190 msec
;; SERVER: 80.87.78.4#53(80.87.78.4)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul  4 17:03:56 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 278
```

below are the result for ping and ping6

```
joseph@joseph-off-lap:~$ ping -c 5 he.net
PING he.net (216.218.186.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from he.net (216.218.186.2): icmp_req=1 ttl=45 time=277 ms
64 bytes from he.net (216.218.186.2): icmp_req=2 ttl=45 time=275 ms
64 bytes from he.net (216.218.186.2): icmp_req=3 ttl=45 time=277 ms
64 bytes from he.net (216.218.186.2): icmp_req=4 ttl=45 time=275 ms
64 bytes from he.net (216.218.186.2): icmp_req=5 ttl=45 time=275 ms

--- he.net ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 21209ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 275.675/276.405/277.621/0.995 ms


joseph@joseph-off-lap:~$ ping6 -c 5 he.net
connect: Network is unreachable
joseph@joseph-off-lap:~$
```

as suggested i'm leaning towards installing `miredo` .is there any configurations/tweaks to make it works? what would you say about `disabling ipv6 vs installing miredo` ?

thanks for reading this. ;)

Comment: No! Guides for other Ubuntu OS's prior to Natty 9 out of 10 are no longer valid.

Comment: mmh sorry what does that mean?

Comment: That the guide you found will not work for Natty.

Comment: any work around out there?

Comment: Instead of disabling IPv6, we should fix whatever the problem is.

Comment: the thing is that , i personally have no idea about what the problem can be.After googling ipv6 is what people seems to have identified as the issue. any idea?

Comment: The question's title is a little misleading. Do we want to disable IPv6 in chrome, disable IPv6 system wide, fix an IPv6-related bug in chrome or an IPv6-related network issue?

Comment: Can't you just disable IPv6 in chrome?

Comment: @black sensei I updated my answer with a part about miredo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Chrome is slow to start loading the page but once it starts loading the page it's fast, there are two things that could be going wrong. The first possibility is that your computer is using a buggy DNS server that doesn't handle requests for IPv6 addresses well. The second possibility is that your computer thinks it has internet IPv6 connectivity when in reality it doesn't.

Run `dig aaaa he.net` and `dig a he.net`. Each one will list a Query time. The times should be within ~200msec of each other. If they are not, you DNS server is what is causing this slowness.

One case to test for is how fast the DNS server will tell you that a website does not have an IPv6 address. You can test this by running something like `dig aaaa bluecc.edu`. It's Query time should be similar to the other times you ran 'dig'. The important thing is that the Query time is short.

IPv6 access itself could be broken. You can test by running `ping -c 5 he.net` and `ping6 -c 5 he.net`. The 'time' for the ping6 should be comparable to just ping, and the 'time' should be at least less 1000 msec. If the ping6 is giving you destination unreachable errors, then your IPv6 connectivity is broken. In that case, you have two options. One is to disable IPv6 and the other is to install [miredo](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/miredo), which will make an IPv6 tunnel, which should fix any connectivity problems. (You shouldn't have to do anything to set up miredo. It should just work. It's also easy to remove if you ever need to with `sudo apt-get remove miredo`)

Comment: thanks will do that.should i put the result here?

Comment: Yes. If you find out more facts about your problem, it doesn't hurt to add them to your question so that people have a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: what do you mean with this question "Is Chromium slow to open?". let me describe how it's starts.first it's google chrome stable(not chromium).and i have 5 sites that open when browser starts.the browser itself opens withing 2seconds and then the tabs show "loading" for quite a while and when the titles come up the pages load relatively faster.same for refresh of the same page

Comment: i've updated the question to include the result of ping vs ping6.and as you have guest it, ipv6 connectivity is broken.

Comment: i've tried miredo for like 3 days and i found the connection still slow.i've now removed it and disable the ipv6 protocol in the `/etc/default/grug` this morning and it seems effective already.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, disabling IPv6 can be done by setting the following in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
```

Don't forget to call `update-grub` afterwards and reboot. This seems to be the most sure-fire way to do it in Ubuntu.

Another way is to set it in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

To disable IPv6 immediately, but not permanently, without reboot:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
# sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

I've found that using `/etc/sysctl.conf` didn't work as expected but I don't exactly remember what the problem was. Maybe the settings were applied too late in the boot process for some applications?

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1" disables the module completely from being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions here:
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-1004.html

It worked perfectly on 10.04, 10.10 and 11.04.